# How to generate a 2D list which will contain numbers from 1..n without using numpy?

Tags: python, list

The 2D list should be like this:

```
matrix = [
             [1, 2, 3, 4],
             [5, 6, 7, 8],
             [9, 10, 11, 12],
             [13, 14, 15, 16]
         ]
```

I am unable to find the logic for this. I have done this using numpy's reshape function. But unable to do without numpy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one simple way:

```
res = [list(range(i, i+4)) for i in range(1, 14, 4)]

print(res)

[[1, 2, 3, 4],
 [5, 6, 7, 8],
 [9, 10, 11, 12],
 [13, 14, 15, 16]]
```

You can also wrap in a generic function:

```
def square(n):
    return [list(range(i, i+n)) for i in range(1, n**2, n)]

res = square(4)
```

**Explanation**

The syntax for `range` construction is `range(start, end, [step])`. `step` is optional; if it is not specified, it is assumed to be 1.

- The first part `range(i, i+n)` creates a range object from `i` to `i+n-1`, inclusive.
- The second part `range(1, n**2, n)` iterates in steps of `n` to `n*n`, not including the final term. Since `end` is non-inclusive, squaring `n` provides the desired cap.

Comment: beat me for a second ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach

```
l = range(1, 17)     #Create a list using range
print([l[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(l), 4)])    #Divide the list into 4 equal chunks
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I like this one too:

```
>> [[i+4*j for i in range(1,5)] for j in range(4)]
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a list-comprehension like this with tuple unpacking:

```
>>> [[*range(i, i+4)] for i in range(1, 14, 4)]
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
```

Answer (score 0):

or you could use the [`grouper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) from the `itertools` recipes to split a given list (or iterable) into an 2d matrix. this is something along those lines:

```
def to2d(items, width):
    return list(list(i) for i in zip(*(iter(items_1d),) * width))

items_1d = list(range(1, 17))   # or just  items_1d = range(1, 17)
print(to2d(items=items_1d, width=4))
```